# load order when defining a module in requirejs?

Tags: requirejs, amd

i know it is possible to use nested require.

```
 require(["site_common/js/config"], function () {
   require(['infrastructure'], function() { ...
```

I 'd like to define a module and it is depend on A.js and A.js is depend on B.js

```
define([B], func() {
  require([A], func() {
     var C = new Foo();
     return C;
  });
});
```

doesn't work. how can I define C which depends on A and A depends on B ?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't normally nest calls to `require`.
Can't you just include it as a normal dependency?

```
require(["site_common/js/config", 'infrastructure'], function (config, infra) { ...
```

---

Or:

file *A.js*

```
define(['B'], function (B) {
    return { b: B };
}
```

file *B.js*

```
define([], function () {
    return { message: "hello!" };
}
```

file *C.js*

```
define(['A'], function (A) {
    return { a: A };
}
```

file *main.js*

```
require(['C'], function (C) {
    alert( C.a.b.message ); // alert box saying "hello!"
});
```